# What is a FIN+ACK message in TCP?

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm working on implementing TCP myself for a class project, and there's one detail I can't seem to understand.  What is a FIN+ACK message?  In the diagram I included here, receipt of a FIN+ACK will take a host from the FIN_WAIT_1 state to the TIME_WAIT state.  Yet, NO state transition in the entire diagram sends a FIN+ACK.  So how could a FIN+ACK ever be received if nothing is ever sending it?

[image]

Comment: The legend makes this clear: this is what happens when the application issues a `close()` operation on the TCP socket.

Comment: What do you mean? It looks like if the application issues a `close()` operation while in the `ESTABLISHED` state, it sends a `FIN`, not a `FIN+ACK`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Client sends FIN, the ACK set on this packet is ACK on last data packet sent.   Remote responds with FIN+ACK, this ACK refers to the client's FIN - Ack number will be incremented.   Most implementations will also RST immediately subsequently.

Comment: @BadZen Really? An implementation that sent FIN-ACK-RST would be broken. It should keep the port in LAST_ACK until it receives the ACK to its own FIN.

Answer (score 5):

When an application calls `close` it moves to `FIN_WAIT_1`

From `FIN_WAIT_1` multiple things can happen:

1. Application receives ACK:

   This means that the peer as acknowledged the last sent data packet. Local application moves to `FIN_WAIT_2`
2. Application receives FIN:

   This indicates that peer has called `close`. And local application should acknowledge that. Hence ACK goes out to peer. Local application moves to `CLOSING`
3. Application receives FIN + ACK:

   What `FIN+ACK` as you put it means is that the peer has called `close` **as well as in the same TCP segment is acknowledging the data received last**. Local application will acknowledge the FIN and this takes the state to `TIME_WAIT`.

Answer (score 5):

TCP is defined by more than just that state diagram, the basic specification can be found in [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-15). One particular statement is as follows (page 15, description of `ACK` field):

> Once a connection is established this is always sent.

So basically this says an ACK must always be present after the initial three-way handshake, including during the four-way disconnect phase. There are subsequently only 2 messages that do not include an ACK:

- The very first SYN as there is nothing to ACK
- A RST as this usually means the connection state is non-existent or so messed up that an ACK does not make sense.

So to answer your question: in that diagram, whenever a FIN is sent, the ACK flag will also be set and an ACK nr will be present, even though it is not explicitly stated.